# Cursor is before the line number during page load

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm using code mirror for the first time and finding it to be awesome!

So, when the page loads for the first time, the cursor goes before line number. But after I type couple of lines, all the texts start showing in proper area after line number. Any thoughts? These are the values that I've set.

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(elt, {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "xml",
  htmlMode: true, 
  lineSeparator: null,
  theme: "default",
  indentUnit: 2,
  tabSize: 4,
  indentWithTabs: true,
  lineWrapping: true, 
  tabindex: 1,
  autofocus: true,
  gutter: true,
  lineWrapping: true  
});
myCodeMirror.setSize(null,1000);
```

[image]

Comment: Found this solution that says 'refresh' should fix the issue. Trying this out. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951737/codemirror-line-numbers-overlapped-with-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `myCodeMirror.refresh();` after `myCodeMirror.setSize(null,1000);` solved the issue.